# flutter : Change ExpansionPanelList Style while not expanded

Tags: flutter

I would like to use the `ExpansionPanelList` and there are properties such as elevation that one can use.

There are no properties to customize the look while the `ExpansionPanelList` is not expanded, in particular the padding between the not-expanded elements and the border color.

How can I customize these elements (and is there a work-around if one can not customize them directly)

Answer (score 1):

As per Flutter documentation `ExpansionPanelList` widget does not provide a direct customization option.

1. You can customize it by wrapping the `ExpansionPanelList` with `ListView` or `Column`.

**Here is an example you can try:**

```
ListView(
  children: [
    // Add any custom widgets or padding here
    ExpansionPanelList(
      // Expansion panel configuration
      expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
        // Handle expansion
      },
      children: [
        // Expansion panels
      ],
    ),
    // Add any custom widgets or padding here
  ],
)
```

2. You can use the `ExpansionPanel` widget. By doing this, you can also fully customize and control the expansion behaviour.

**Here is an example you can try:**

```
class CustomExpansionPanelList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<CustomExpansionPanel> children;

  CustomExpansionPanelList({required this.children});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        // Add any custom widgets or padding here
        for (var panel in children)
          panel,
        // Add any custom widgets or padding here
      ],
    );
  }
}

class CustomExpansionPanel extends StatefulWidget {
  // Custom properties and constructor

  @override
  _CustomExpansionPanelState createState() => _CustomExpansionPanelState();
}

class _CustomExpansionPanelState extends State<CustomExpansionPanel> {
  bool _isExpanded = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ExpansionPanel(
      // Expansion panel configuration
      isExpanded: _isExpanded,
      headerBuilder: (context, isExpanded) {
        // Header content
        // Add any custom styling for the header when not expanded
      },
      body: Container(
        // Body content
        // Add any custom styling for the body when expanded
      ),
      canTapOnHeader: true,
      onExpansionChanged: (isExpanded) {
        setState(() {
          _isExpanded = isExpanded;
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I hope this might help you to build or customize `ExpansionPanelList`.